# JQuery Ui 1.9.2: No navigation with autocomplete. Can't see the bug. Help Please?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I trying to add autocomplete to my search bar. It works but the navigation is kinda "hidden" See:

[image: no bar]
As you see the navigation "tab" is hidden. I checked my style.css and I added a reset css code:

Style.css

```
    html, body, div, span, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
abbr, address, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp,
small, strong, sub, sup, var,
b, i,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
}
* { all: unset }

body {
    line-height:1;
}

article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,
footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section { 
    display:block;
}

nav ul {
    list-style:none;
}

blockquote, q {
    quotes:none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content:'';
    content:none;
}

a {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
}

/* change colours to suit your needs */
ins {
    background-color:#ff9;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}

/* change colours to suit your needs */
mark {
    background-color:#ff9;
    color:#000; 
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight:bold;
}

del {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

abbr[title], dfn[title] {
    border-bottom:1px dotted;
    cursor:help;
}

table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
}

/* change border colour to suit your needs */
hr {
    display:block;
    height:1px;
    border:0;   
    border-top:1px solid #cccccc;
    margin:1em 0;
    padding:0;
}

input, select {
    vertical-align:middle;
}

/*                          - - - - -  - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
      -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
    .form-wrapper {
      position: absolute;
        width: 450px;
        padding: 15px;
        margin: 230px auto 80px 396px;

    }

    .form-wrapper input {
        width: 400px;
        height: 40px;
        padding: 10px 5px;
        float: left;
        font: bold 20px 'Arial', 'trebuchet MS', 'Tahoma';
        border: 2;

        -moz-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
        border-radius: 9px;
    }

    .form-wrapper input:focus {
        outline: 0;
        background: #fff;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8) inset;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8) inset;
        box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.8) inset;
    }

    .form-wrapper input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
       color: #999;
       font-weight: normal;
       font-style: italic;
    }

    .form-wrapper input:-moz-placeholder {
        color: #999;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: italic;
    }

    .form-wrapper input:-ms-input-placeholder {
        color: #999;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: italic;
    }

  /*  - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  - - - - - - -  - - */

h3{ /* results for %% */
    position: absolute;
    margin: 330px auto auto 550px;
    font-family: "DIN Condensed", Arial;
    font-size: 30px;

}

.comment {
    margin: 380px 310px -350px 350px;

}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #005ca9;
}



.link{

    font-size: 25px;
    font-family:  "Avenir Next", "Helvetica Neue", Arial;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;

}

.link:hover{

    text-decoration: none;
}

img {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 90px auto auto 340px;
    background-repeat : no-repeat;
}

.nothing{
  font-size: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 430px auto auto 466px;
}

.maybe{
  font-size: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 430px auto auto 376px;
}

.autocomplete{
  text-decoration: none; 
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

I checked chrome dev tools and I found something interesting. In fact, when clicked, the tab width is higly increased, see:

[image: the bar]
But I don't know what to do, JsFiddle show no errors with my app (http://jsfiddle.net/6yXxW/). I'm new to Jquery UI, can someone help me?

I forgot to share the html file with the form and js(Django app):

search.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'style.css' %}" >
<img src="{% static "monky.png" %}" alt="Monky" galleryimg="no"/>
<form method="get" action="." class="form-wrapper cf">

            {% for field in form %}
        <div class="fieldWrapper">
             {{ field}}
        </div>

            {% endfor %}
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function monkeyPatchAutocomplete() {

    var oldFn = $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderItem;

    $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        var re = new RegExp("^" + this.term, "i");
        var t = item.label.replace(re, "<span style='font-weight:bold;color:black;'>" + this.term + "</span>");
        return $("<p></p>")
            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
            .append("<a class='autocomplete'>" + t + "</a>")
            .appendTo(ul);
    };
}

$(function () {

    monkeyPatchAutocomplete();

    var availableTags = [
        "Comédie",
        "Horreur",
        "Coloré",
        "corala"];

    $("#search_bar").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
});
```

Comment: Well without being able to reproduce the issue in a fiddle, I don't know that I would be able to solve what is causing the error.  But if you want to try a work around you could try some css like the following: `.ui-autocomplete {border: 1px solid #aaaaaa!important; width:250px!important; } ` Where you make sure the width is wide enough for all your words.  That could be a work around for you while you look into what is going on..

Comment: It worked !!!  But there's a little problem, when you navigate the background of the suggestion selected still white look : http://i.imgur.com/m6cA1gt.png.

Comment: Hmm you could try. `ui-state-focus { border: 1px solid #999999!important;
background: #dadada!important;
font-weight: normal!important;
color: #212121;!important }`

Comment: You could also try moving your code around to where your Bootstrap CSS gets loaded last on the page.  That might help.  So for example if you have multiple `<style>` tags move your bootstrap to the very bottom.

Comment: It worked ! Thank you very much, you deserve it !

Comment: your welcome, I added it as the answer but hopefully eventually you can figure out a solution without having to override the css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving your bootstrap `<style>` tag to the bottom of your `<style>`'s so that it loads last.

Or you could try overriding the `css` like:

`.ui-autocomplete {
     border: 1px solid #aaaaaa!important; width:250px!important; 
    }
  .ui-state-focus { 
       border: 1px solid #999999!important; background: #dadada!important; 
       font-weight:normal!important; color: #212121;!important 
   }`